# How to forward traffic to socks proxy?

Tags: iptables

Installation is like this:
on server1, use `ssh -D server1:1080 root@server2` to setup a socks proxy.
meanwhile, on server1, there is an IPsec/xauth VPN server running with vpn network 192.168.42.0/24. Then laptop does VPN connect to server1.

After VPN connection, if I config laptop to use socks proxy server1:1080, the laptop can access server2 network through the SSH socks proxy successfully. But I hope to forward traffic from VPN network to server1:1080 transparently on server1 without config laptop to use socks proxy. I guess I should use iptables.

Answer (score 1):

Man,

what you're looking for is called [redsocks](https://github.com/darkk/redsocks)

From the excerpt:

> This tool allows you to redirect any TCP connection to SOCKS or HTTPS
>   proxy using your firewall, so redirection may be system-wide or
>   network-wide.

Comment: yeah, I found redsocks to proxy tcp connections, I am still struggling with UDP connection. It seems redsocks can do UDP, but I haven't done it successfully